# Marshalling a fixed-size buffer from C# to extern

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm having some difficulties using a struct to call some Windows kernel32 function. I'm trying to call the function [FindFirstStreamW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364424%28VS.85%29.aspx), which return, among others, a [WIN32_FIND_STREAM_DATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365741(v=vs.85).aspx) struct.

I use this struct in C# to represent it :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct WIN32_FIND_STREAM_DATA
{
    public long StreamSize;
    public fixed char StreamName [MAX_PATH + 32];
}
```

But I have problems using the StreamName afterward. After a call to the function, the StreamName buffer seems to contains a semicolon (which is expected) and then only random data.

I experimented by replacing the fixed buffer by consecutives char such as s1, s2, s3 etc... and it worked (s1 contained ':', then s2 '$' etc... all correct !).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct WIN32_FIND_STREAM_DATA
{
    public long StreamSize;
    public char s1;
    public char s2;
    public char s3;
}
```

I must therefore miss something but can't find what and after 8 firefox windows filled with google researches, I'm pretty desperate.

Here is my DLLImport :

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindFirstStreamW(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
    StreamInfoLevels infoLevel,
    out WIN32_FIND_STREAM_DATA data,
    int reserved = 0
    );
```

And there is my test code :

```
WIN32_FIND_STREAM_DATA data = default(WIN32_FIND_STREAM_DATA);
IntPtr search = FindFirstStreamW(D_TMP_TESTHANDLE_TXT, StreamInfoLevels.FindStreamInfoStandard, out data);
Debug.WriteLine(data.StreamSize);
Debug.WriteLine(new string(data.StreamName));
FindClose(search);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are corrupting the stack with this declaration, it has a, cough, interesting affect on the fixed buffer.  +32 needs to be +36.  And you need to use CharSet = CharSet.Unicode in the [StructLayout] attribute.

Comment: Can you explain where is the stack corrupted please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your struct - compared to the variant where you actually have distinct characters - is probably that it does not get marshalled as expected because arrays are by reference and not by value by default when using .NET.

Read [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx) about string marshalling for more information.

So I'd try it with something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct WIN32_FIND_STREAM_DATA
{
    public long StreamSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=MAX_PATH+36)]
    public string StreamName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was assuming that a fixed-size buffer was indeed the same as individual sequential characters, specially since the size of the resulting struct was the same.